# get max and min value from child multidimensional php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have array like this:

```
$listRest = 
Array
([restaurants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [restaurant] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Pipe and Puff
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [city_id] => 74
                                )
                            [average_cost_for_two] => 150000
                            [user_rating] => Array
                                (
                                    [aggregate_rating] => 3.8
                                )
                        )
                )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [restaurant] => Array
                    (
                        [location] => Array
                        (
                                [city_id] => 74
                            )
                        [average_cost_for_two] => 300000
                        [user_rating] => Array
                            (
                                [aggregate_rating] => 3.4
                            )
                    )
            )
```

i want to find the min value of "average_cost_for_two" and "aggregate_rating" but it says "max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array"

this is my code

```
$rest = $listRest['restaurants'];
foreach($listRest as $value)
{
  $price = $value['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'];
  $rating = $value['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'];
}
echo max($price)."</br>.";
echo max($rating);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should initialise arrays to put your price and rating values there. Also when you add another value, you should put to another element of array. [Max](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.max.php) function chooses the highest value from array.

```
$rest = $listRest['restaurants'];
$price = [];
$rating = [];
foreach($rest as $value)
{
  $price[] = $value['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'];
  $rating[] = $value['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'];
}
echo max($price)."</br>.";
echo max($rating);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't missunderstood your question, you've to try like this to assign each and every price and rating like this `$price[]` and `$rating[]` respectively.

```
$price = $rating = [];
$rest = $listRest['restaurants'];
foreach($listRest as $value)
{
  $price[] = $value['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'];   // see the change here
  $rating[] = $value['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating']; // see the change here
}
echo max($price)."</br>.";
echo max($rating);

echo min($price)."</br>.";
echo min($rating);
```

Answer (score 1):

> $rest = $listRest['restaurants'];
>
> foreach($listRest as $value)

Should instead be

```
$rest = $listRest['restaurants']; 

foreach($rest as $value)
```

---

> $price = $value['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'];
>
> $rating = $value['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'];

- Will overwrite the previous values of $price and $rating, therefore, max($price) and max($rating) will not work.
- Also as $price and $rating are defined inside the forloop, they will not be accessible outside it.

  - Therefore, instantiate $price and $rating outside of the forloop as `$price[]` and `$rating[]`.

---

> echo max($price).".";
>
> echo max($rating);

Max function works on an array, therefore inside the forloop you will have to push (insert) each value obtained by the loop to $price and $rating, respectively i.e.,

```
$price[] = $value['restaurant']['average_cost_for_two'];
$rating[] = $value['restaurant']['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put all you data un an array and then, execute max() on it.
I created a live PHP script correcting your code : [get max and min value from child multidimensional php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cfa47c65ba95df82b46afa187668ea0fc7aaa44)